# Java Application Hangs SomeTimes

Tags: java, rpa, blueprism

We are trying to automate the Java Browser based application using BluePrism. I am using Internet explorer as application and enabled Java techniques in application moduler. I am able to spy the elements and able to perform operations like focus, write, read, select tree views etc. But some times Java application will hang and blue prism will not respond. So some of the operation will fail because of this i.e., Blueprism unable to select the country or state from the drop down. We are following all the best practices provided by blue prism but still we are facing this issues some times. Please let me know for any solution.

```
Even manually if we open the application we are getting the below error sometimes.
```

Note: Java application and BluePrism are hosted inside Azure VM

```
Log ID: F146EEDB78D9BFFE58B1EA1C8F8D8C44:138

CLIENT LOG:
NA,thread applet-com.application.gap.GTAppletStart.class-1,MESSAGE,NA,[12-15-20 15:52:01.897],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Loaded schema cache in 890 ms"
NA,thread applet-com.application.gap.GTAppletStart.class-1,WARNING,NA,[12-15-20 15:52:03.081],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Retrieving single value for table GT_USER_PREFS_TYPESAFE, column REDIRECT_USER_NAME, row 0"
NA,thread applet-com.application.gap.GTAppletStart.class-1,WARNING,NA,[12-15-20 15:52:03.114],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Retrieving single value for table GT_USER_PREFS_TYPESAFE, column DEFAULT_ACCT_SG_NAME, row 0"
NA,thread applet-com.application.gap.GTAppletStart.class-1,WARNING,NA,[12-15-20 15:52:03.145],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Retrieving single value for table GT_USER_PREFS_TYPESAFE, column DEFAULT_CUST_SG_NAME, row 0"
NA,thread applet-com.application.gap.GTAppletStart.class-1,MESSAGE,NA,[12-15-20 15:52:03.273],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Automatic saving preference not set."
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,ERROR,NA,[12-15-20 15:53:16.726],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Connection reset"
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:113)
    at com.application.gap.db.GTDataProxy.doOperationBatch(GTDataProxy.java:279)
    at com.application.gap.domain.GTDomain.load(GTDomain.java:236)
    at com.application.gap.domain.GTDomain.getPresentationBatch(GTDomain.java:120)
    at com.application.gap.domain.GTDomain.getPresentation(GTDomain.java:110)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelNavigationForm$DynamicNavAdapter.getBaseOperations(GTSelNavigationForm.java:244)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelNavigationManager$ListBaseNavAdapter.nodeListOperations(GTSelNavigationManager.java:1660)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTListview$ListMouseListener.maybeShowPopup(GTListview.java:584)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTListview$ListMouseListener.mouseReleased(GTListview.java:551)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,MESSAGE,NA,[12-15-20 15:53:16.727],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Caught SocketException: retrying to connect 1"
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,ERROR,NA,[12-15-20 15:55:11.705],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Connection reset"
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:113)
    at com.application.gap.db.GTDataProxy.doOperationBatch(GTDataProxy.java:279)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.doDataOperationBatch(GTSelection.java:296)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.getTreeResults(GTSelection.java:413)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:670)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:585)
    at com.application.aim.gui.AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.nodeExpanding(AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.java:608)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.getDynamicNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:365)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.createChildNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:148)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildNodes(GTTreeModel.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildCount(GTTreeModel.java:77)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.ensurePathIsExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.updateExpandedDescendants(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.treeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.expandPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTJTreeHelper.expandPath(GTJTreeHelper.java:83)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.toggleExpandState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.handleExpandControlClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.checkForClickInExpandControl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,MESSAGE,NA,[12-15-20 15:55:11.706],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Caught SocketException: retrying to connect 1"
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,ERROR,NA,[12-15-20 15:55:54.713],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Connection reset"
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:113)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.db.GTDataProxy.doOperationBatch(GTDataProxy.java:279)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.doDataOperationBatch(GTSelection.java:296)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.getTreeResults(GTSelection.java:413)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:670)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:585)
    at com.application.aim.gui.AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.nodeExpanding(AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.java:608)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.getDynamicNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:365)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.createChildNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:148)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildNodes(GTTreeModel.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildCount(GTTreeModel.java:77)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.ensurePathIsExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.updateExpandedDescendants(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.treeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.expandPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTJTreeHelper.expandPath(GTJTreeHelper.java:83)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.toggleExpandState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.handleExpandControlClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.checkForClickInExpandControl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,MESSAGE,NA,[12-15-20 15:55:54.714],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Caught SocketException: retrying to connect 2"
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,ERROR,NA,[12-15-20 15:56:37.718],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,,"Connection reset"
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:113)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.db.GTDataProxy.doOperationBatch(GTDataProxy.java:279)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.doDataOperationBatch(GTSelection.java:296)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelection.getTreeResults(GTSelection.java:413)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:670)
    at com.application.gap.selections.GTSelectionRenderer.expandTree(GTSelectionRenderer.java:585)
    at com.application.aim.gui.AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.nodeExpanding(AIMTaskChecklistTreeManager.java:608)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.getDynamicNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:365)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeNodeFactory.createChildNodes(GTTreeNodeFactory.java:148)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildNodes(GTTreeModel.java:144)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTTreeModel.getChildCount(GTTreeModel.java:77)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.expand(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.ensurePathIsExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.updateExpandedDescendants(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.treeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireTreeExpanded(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setExpandedState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTree.expandPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTJTreeHelper.expandPath(GTJTreeHelper.java:83)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.toggleExpandState(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.handleExpandControlClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.checkForClickInExpandControl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
NA,AWT-EventQueue-2,ERROR,NA,[12-15-20 16:03:46.012],0,username@ABC.com,GT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL3,About menu,"Connection reset"
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTUrlConnection.connect(GTUrlConnection.java:113)
    at com.application.gap.GTAbout.getProxyAbout(GTAbout.java:150)
    at com.application.gap.GTAbout.<init>(GTAbout.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.gap.util.GTClassLoader.getClassInstance(GTClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTGui.doLaunch(GTGui.java:606)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTGui$MenuItemListener.actionPerformed(GTGui.java:2003)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTControl.fireActionEvent(GTControl.java:120)
    at com.application.gap.gui.GTMenuItem.actionPerformed(GTMenuItem.java:317)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer, you would need to post some logs from the server to get some idea why it drops the connection.

Comment: I tried to change the proxy and application is working fine i.e., there is no “connection reset” issue now. With old Proxy we were getting Connection Reset issue intermediately. Can you please let me know what may be the root cause for connection reset issue in the old proxy ? Is it proxy issue or application is blocking the request for old proxy ? or any other root cause?